# алгоритм поиска по картинке

Tags: алгоритм

есть массив i на j, каждый элемент массива хранит в себе цвет пикселя картинки. Сама картинка представляет из себя preview других картинок, разделенных между собой белой полосой, причем сами превьшки так же могут содержать в себе некие последовательности белых пикселей[image: пример]

стоит задача найти центры этих превьюшек, кто подскажет как ее решить?

Comment: А что такое центр в вашем понимании? Это важно.

Comment: И я бы разделил задачу на две: разрезать большую картинку на маленькие, и найти центр каждой отдельной маленькой картинки.

Comment: Кстати, откуда берётся большая картинка? Почему она не порезана на части заранее? Если это preview ваших картинок, просто не склеивайте всё в одну кучу, вам же легче будет.

Comment: под центром тут понимаю ширину и высоту превью деленную на 2

Comment: Ага, тогда вторая задача самоочевидна, и вопрос в первой.

Comment: история умалчивает откуда берется большая картинка, стоит задача разобраться с тем что есть :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Окей, а чем не подходит наивный алгоритм?

Идёте в цикле по X. Для каждого X проверяете, состоит ли весь столбец с данным X из белых клеток (назовём для краткости «белый столбец»). Минус первый столбец можно считать белым для простоты алгоритма. Если этот столбец белый, а предыдущий нет, то данный X — конец картинки, запоминаете его. Если этот столбец не белый, а предыдущий был белый, это начало новой картинки, запоминаете его.

То же для координаты Y.

Имея начало и конец картинки по X и Y, вычисляете средние арифметические.

Comment: и мне приходила в голову такая идея,  но смутило то что некоторые превью могут быть белыми "наскозь" по одной из осей, и может такое случится что вся строка/столбец может быть белым

Comment: @user193361: Может случиться, конечно. Если у вас например все три средних preview в одном и том же месте имеют белую полосу, тогда вообще никак не отличить. Разве что вы знаете ещё и минимальную ширину белой полосы.